# File not Found Exception was unhandled

Tags: dll, microsoft-graph-api

I created a `Project A` class library that reference `azure.identity` and built `A.dll`.

Then I created a `Project B` and imported in `A.dll`, but error comes out that could not load assembly:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `project B` add NuGet packages `Azure.Identity` and `Microsoft.Graph` in version 4.45.

Or if your `project A` and `project B` are part of the same solution then add [project reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2022#add-a-reference) to `project A` in `project B` instead of importing `A.dll`.